# linq check what condition return false in multiple and-conditions

Tags: linq

I have following sample of code:

```
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
temp.Add("bla bla");
temp.Add("111");
temp.Add("222");
temp.Add("1111111");
temp.Where(x => x.Length <= 5 && x.Contains("1")).ToList();
```

And I expect result:

Elements:

[0] - "bla bla" - result false - crashed on condition **Length <= 5**

[1] - "111" - result true

[2] - "222" - result false - crashed on condition **x.Contains("1")**

[3] - "1111111" - result false - crashed on condition **Length <= 5**

Can I somehow do it?

Comment: So, instead of filtering you'd like to get all the elements with an additional field mentioning true/false and reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By splitting the criteria in a separate list (as `Func<string,bool`s), you can test each individual setting. One step further, by wrapping them as an `Expression<>`, the contents of the (failed) criterium can be obtained:

```
List<string> temp = new List<string>{"bla bla", "111","222","1111111"};

var criteria = new Expression<Func<string,bool>>[]{x => x.Length <= 5 , x => x.Contains("1")}
    .Select(c=>new{Test=c.Compile(), Name = c.ToString()}).ToList(); //get precompiled lambdas with their names, based on the lambda expressions

var results = from s in temp    
    let fail = criteria.FirstOrDefault(c=>!c.Test(s)) //get the first criterium to fail (if any)
    select new {Value = s, Result = fail ==null , FailedOn = fail?.Name};


foreach(var m in results) //test output
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0} [{1}] {2}" , m.Value, m.Result, m.Result ? null : " crashed on " + m.FailedOn);
```

Results of the above:

- Value: bla bla [False] crashed on x => (x.Length <= 5)
- Value: 111 [True]
- Value: 222 [False]  crashed on x => x.Contains("1")
- Value: 1111111 [False] crashed on x => (x.Length <= 5)

Comment: Thank you! It is what I need

Answer (score 0):

As I checked your code it is executing correctly and giving the correct result

```
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            temp.Add("bla bla");
            temp.Add("111");
            temp.Add("222");
            temp.Add("1111111");
            var result= temp.Where(x => x.Length <= 5 && x.Contains("1")).ToList();

            foreach(var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("x={0}", item);
            }
```

[image]

If you want to return true instead you can use something as:
 var result1= temp.Where(x => x.Length <= 5 && x.Contains("1")).Select(x=>true).ToList();